# GLES10.glPointSize(float size) does not work in java point cloud example

Tags: java, google-project-tango

I am trying to make the rendered points in the java point cloud example bigger but I can't seem to get it to work. As you probably know it uses the Rajawali renderer.

What I do is change this code in Points.java:

```
    @Override
    public void preRender() {
        super.preRender();
        setDrawingMode(GLES20.GL_POINTS);
        GLES10.glPointSize(5.0f);    // <---- A bigger value here does nothing
    }
```

But even though I increase the float parameter to glPointSize the points stay the same size as before in the app. Anyone know how to make the points bigger or any other way to do this?

Thanks!﻿

Comment: Have you tried to put the "glPointSize" before the "setDrawingMode" ?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply a custom shader.

Here is how I draw points using VertexShader:

```
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 10.0 // <-- set points size
  vColor = aColor;
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Comment: I tried this:

`private static String mVShader =
            "void main() {" +
                    "gl_PointSize = 20.0;" +
                    "vColor = aColor;" +
                    "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";` 
and then 

`public void preRender() {
        super.preRender();
        Material mMat = new Material(new VertexShader(mVShader), new FragmentShader());
        setMaterial(mMat);
        setDrawingMode(GLES20.GL_POINTS);}`

I am not very familiar with shaders. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I personally don't use Rajawali, but I've tried to run this sample and saw than custom shaders don't work. I think there is a problem with custom shaders in Rajawali. Rajawali [had an issue about it](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/1567)